# Sencha Touch Login validation with MSSQL database

Tags: java, hibernate, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to build a client/server application using Sencha Touch 2 on the client side and Java/hibernate/MSSQL database technology on the server side. To get started I created the client side user login frame.Now i need help to implement the server side of the application. 
That is, to take the username/password and send it to the server and validate if the login is correct or not. Can somebody please help me to achieve this part. I am using Tomcat as the container for my server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very Easy,Below code not totally working ,but it will give you just an idea,to start.

1. Create Login form in sencha touch(Login.js)
2. Write a Login Controller in sencha touch which is responsible for making Ajax request from front end to backend. This controller should contain below line of code inside a function.

   var user = Ext.getCmp('user_name');

   var pass = Ext.getCmp('password');

   // For security purpose you should always pass credntial in encrypted format

   var param = {user_name:user,password:pass};

   var jsonData = JSON.stringify(param);

Ext.Ajax.request({

```
       url: 'http://server_ip:8080/backend/authenticate',


       jsonData : param,


    success: function(response){
      Ext.Msg.Alert(null,"Login Successfule");
      //You can write your own logic to display any other screen
    }



    failure : function(error){
      Ext.Msg.Alert(null,"Unable to authenticate user");
    }
```

});

3.Now prepare you back end using any frame work in java let say Spring MVC.
4. Write a controller

```
 @Controller
  public class AuthenticateController{
     @RequestMapping(value="authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
     @ResponseBody
     public String authenticateUser((@RequestBody String json){
        //Now by using json data you can verify user by querying DB,and return your own message.
     }
  }
```